# How do I concatenate multiple pandas dataframe columns(Address details) into a single column, space delimited, and ignoring empty strings?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I've got a pandas dataframe that contains a ton of address info. Aka

```
AddressNumber
StreetNamePrefix
StreetName
StreetNameSuffix
StreetNamePreDirectional
StreetNamePostDirectional
OccupancySuite
```

I'd like to combine everything except for OccupancySuite into Address1

I can get address2 easily enough, it's OccupancySuite.

What I'm getting hung up on is combining the rest of the columns, separated by a space, and ignoring the column AND space if it's null. I'd rather not have multiple spaces between address parts due to multiple null columns.

What I have currently is probably pretty hacky, but it gets me there minus the additional spaces between the columns/words.

```
#Example Pandas DF with two addresses
import pandas as pd
data = [['123','','','easy','st','',''],['500','N','County Road','3932','','East','']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['AddressNumber','StreetNamePreDirectional','StreetNamePrefix','StreetName','StreetNameSuffix','StreetNamePostDirectional','OccupancySuite'])


df['Address1']= df['AddressNumber'].fillna('') + ' ' + df['StreetNamePreDirectional'].fillna('') + ' ' + df['StreetNamePrefix'].fillna('') + ' ' + df['StreetName'].fillna('') + ' ' + df['StreetNameSuffix'].fillna('') + ' ' + df['StreetNamePostDirectional'].fillna('')

df.to_csv('localpath\\cleaned_addresses.csv')
```

If you open said csv, you'll see

```
123   easy st
500 N County Road 3932  East
```

What I'm needing is

```
123 easy st
500 N County Road 3932 East
```

Answer (score 0):

I Hope this helps you:

I added the column "Address1" to the data frame.

Then, you can perform a for cycle over the len of the data frame (in order to work with the rows) and over the elements in the columns of the data frame.

With an if statement you can ignore the two last columns "OcupancySuite", "Address1" and ignoring the null space.

```
df["Address1"]=''
for a in range(0, len(df)):
    for element in df.columns:
        if element in ["OcupancySuite", "Address1"]:
            continue
        values=df[element].iloc[a]
        if not values:
            continue
        else:
            df["Address1"].iloc[a]+=df[element].iloc[a] + ' '
```

And if the value is not null you can add the info with the space. (last line).
Here you can see more info about the [iloc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) method.

```
df.to_csv('localpath\\cleaned_addresses.csv')
```

then you will have the correct spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix your answer by replacing multiple spaces with a single space on pandas

```
df['Address1'].str.replace(r'\s+',' ')
```

Also, you could concat your strings more succinctly with an apply.

```
concat_cols = ['AddressNumber',
'StreetNamePreDirectional',
'StreetNamePrefix',
'StreetName',
'StreetNameSuffix',
'StreetNamePostDirectional']

df['Address1'] = df[concat_cols].apply(lambda x:' '.join(x.values), axis=1)
df['Address1'] = df['Address1'].str.replace(r'\s+',' ')
```